Constant in front of Riemann-Liouville process and terminology
Consider a Riemann-Liouville process of the form:
$$ B^H_t = c_H \int_0^t (t-s)^{-H-1/2} dB_s$$
Why can the constant $c_H$ be changed without affecting the properties of the process (as it will change its variance)?
So far, I have encountered different definitions of Riemann-Liouville process, some of them with a constant $c_H=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2+H)}$ (cf. Mandelbrot and Van Ness (1968)), others with $c_H=\sqrt{2H}$ (cf. Marinucci (1999)) or even $c_H=1$.
Are they all equivalent definitions for the Riemann-Liouville process? or should they be referred to as equivalent definitions of a simple Volterra Gaussian process?
